# Slow SQL query based on from date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, optimization

I was given a query to run (below), where in the application I'm creating the from date can be changed at run time.  So if I run a start date of '1/1/2010', I retrieve a lot more data (216620 rows returned) then if I used a date 3 days ago '10/17/2017' (1006 rows returned), but that query for some reason takes extremely long, and in my application it times out.

Should this query be optimized somehow, or could this be a server/hardware issue? I just find this strange a query for the past 3 days takes so much longer than a query for data spanning multiple years, and unfortunately times-out in my WinForms application

```
SELECT AC.account_and_parents As Account, 
    TR.IBLoad as [Load ID], 
    LD.load_inboundBOL as [Customer Details],
    TR.ItemNumber as ITEMNUM, 
    IT.[Description] As[Description], 
    TR.ToPalletID As[Pallet ID],
    Format(TR.Receivedate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as Receive_Date, 
    TR.QTY as NETWEIGHT, 
    TR.WeightGross as [Gross Weight], 
    TR.ContainerType, 
    TR.InvenType,
    TR.Route,
    tr.ToWarehouse  as Warehouse,
    tr.category as Category, 
    tr.FGatIntake as [FG at Intake],
    CASE 
    When TR.FGatIntake = 1
    THEN
        (SELECT TOP 1 tr.ItemNumber FROM [databaseName].[dbo].[Transaction] TR1 WHERE TR1.ToPalletID = TR.ToPalletID and TransCode = 'FRCPT')
    END As[Finished Good]
    FROM [databaseName].[dbo].[Transaction] TR
    INNER JOIN [databaseName].[dbo].[Item] IT 
    on tr.ItemNumber = IT.ItemNumber
    INNER JOIN som5.dbo.Loads LD 
    on TR.IBLoad = LD.OID 
    INNER JOIN [SOM5].[dbo].[Accounts] AC
    on ld.load_Account = AC.OID

             --  PROBLEM IS HERE. Lots or records (January start) are fast,
             --    but few records (October start) are *very* slow. 
    WHERE (TransDateTime Between '10/16/2017' and '10/19/2017')
    and Transcode = 'BRCPT'
    and ToPalletID not in (Select FromPalletID FROM [SOM5].[dbo].[Transaction] where TransCode = 'UNBRCPT') 
        ORDER BY Receive_Date,[Load ID],[Pallet ID]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a query plan we can see to identify the bottle neck

Comment: I edited my post to put up the query plan. Hope that gives you enough information.

Comment: Not sure how big your Transaction table is, but that nested loop with a clustered index scan on both sides of it could benefit from at least one, if not two, NCI's on the transaction table.

Comment: 96% of you execution time is on the index scans. Maybe the faster date is easier to access. How is the fragmentation? Are you getting slow io on the disk?

Comment: The Transaction table is 492443 rows in total. There isn't any IO issues or fragmentation issues. 

I was looking into using maybe an indexed view, but from what I read, that's better in situations where there are few writes, many reads. But this table has around 250 writes per day.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the original query is not using the Where clause to filter rows soon enough.

I would try rewriting the query, putting the where clause for the main table in a sub query. The sub-query should have priority, returning a small subset of data; then these fewer rows will join to the other tables and go through the CASE statement. As for why the potentially bigger dataset executes so quicky... I'm not sure but I do know SQL Server caches results from previous queries.

```
SELECT AC.account_and_parents As Account, 
       TR.[Load ID], 
       LD.load_inboundBOL as [Customer Details],
       TR.ITEMNUM, 
       IT.[Description] As[Description], 
       TR.[Pallet ID],
       Format(TR.Receivedate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as Receive_Date, 
       TR.NETWEIGHT, 
       TR.[Gross Weight], 
       TR.ContainerType, 
       TR.InvenType,
       TR.Route,
       tr.Warehouse,
       tr.category as Category, 
       tr.[FG at Intake],
       CASE 
       When TR.[FG at Intake] = 1
       THEN (SELECT TOP 1 tr.ItemNumber FROM [databaseName].[dbo].[Transaction] TR1 WHERE TR1.ToPalletID = TR.[Pallet ID] and TransCode = 'FRCPT')
    END As[Finished Good]
  FROM (
          SELECT IBLoad as [Load ID],
                 ItemNumber as ITEMNUM, 
                 ToPalletID As[Pallet ID],
                 Format(Receivedate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as Receive_Date, 
                 QTY as NETWEIGHT, 
                 WeightGross as [Gross Weight], 
                 ContainerType, 
                 InvenType,
                 Route,
                 ToWarehouse  as Warehouse,
                 category as Category, 
                 FGatIntake as [FG at Intake]
            FROM [databaseName].[dbo].[Transaction]
           WHERE TransDateTime >= '2017-10-16'
             AND TransDateTime <= '2017-10-19'
       ) AS TR INNER JOIN [databaseName].[dbo].[Item] IT on tr.ITEMNUM = IT.ItemNumber
               INNER JOIN som5.dbo.Loads LD on TR.[Load ID] = LD.OID 
               INNER JOIN [SOM5].[dbo].[Accounts] AC on ld.load_Account = AC.OID
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I found one way to make the query faster, though I'm not sure why it works. 
 I selected from the Transaction table (492k+ rows), the modified the query having the issue to, at the end, query from that. I can't explain why that worked, but it made the query quick.